# Fatal error: Duplicate keys of type 'ArraySlice<Node>' were found in a Dictionary. But I am not using any Dictionaries

Tags: swift, data-structures, hashable, equatable

I have a tree data structure where each node has an id, type and children:

```
final class Node: Equatable, Hashable {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  var type: String = ""
  var children: [Node] = []

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      hasher.combine(id)
      hasher.combine(type)
      hasher.combine(children)
  }

  public static func ==(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
      lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.children == rhs.children
  }

  func add(child: Node) { // added as requested. called from a Button
    self.children.append(child)
  }

}
```

When I run the program and start adding nodes, either at the top level (an array stored in a StateObject) or beneath an existing node, I get `Fatal error: Duplicate keys of type 'ArraySlice<Node>' were found in a Dictionary`. This happens not the first, sometimes not the second, but the 3rd or 4th time I add a node. Is there a dictionary in the system somewhere used by SwiftUI or otherwise? I do not have any dictionaries in my data structures, nor am I slicing any arrays that I am aware of. This worked until yesterday...

Thx!

Comment: "When I run the program and start adding nodes, either at the top level (an array stored in a StateObject) or beneath an existing node" You should show us this code

Comment: Isn't it sufficient only to hash the (unique) `id` of the object?

Comment: @vadian definitely it is

Comment: I have changed the code to only hash the `id` and it appears to be working now. I must have gotten lucky thus far. The only issue is that now my func `==` is really only useful for hashing. Does that mean I just need to write my own function to test for `node.type == node.type` ? Is that more or less standard practice in this situation? Or does it actually matter if `hash()` and `==` are using the same properties? Thanks all.

Comment: Using tree nodes for `Hashable` and `Equatable` is a very bad practice. Imagine you have 8 levels and any check for equality has to traverse the **entire** hierarchy. This is unnecessarily expensive. If the class has an unique identifier then two objects are equal if the identifiers are equal. Period.

Comment: When crashing, were you adding childs making a circular tree? Might be the issue, comparing/hashing the children causing an issue.